# Installing Python 3.4 after Un installing Python 2.5 in Windows

Tags: windows, numpy, installation, registry, python-3.4

I am trying to install Python 3.4 on Windows 8 after un-installing Python 2.5.

I installed Python 3.4.1 - x86 msi package and during that process it never gave a prompt of Remove/Repair/Change Python that usually pops up if there is previous version already installed.

I used x86 version as I wanted to use NumPy too and it supports this only.

I chose "install for all users" option but in my Registry -HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-> SOFTWARE->Python-> PythonCore it is showing Python2.5 not 3.4.1

Though Control Panel lists only Python 3.4.1 as active program.

Also due to this I am facing problems in installing NumPy as it shows error of "can't create key" during installation.

Also after searching for possible problems in stackoverflow site itself I tried below commands in cmd prompt.

```
C:\>assoc .py
```

.py=Python.File

```
C:\>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%1" %*

C:\>assoc .pyw
```

.pyw=Python.NoConFile

```
C:\>ftype Python.NoConFile
Python.NoConFile="C:\WINDOWS\pyw.exe" "%1" %*
```

Please tell how to solve this.

Comment: 32-bit Python uses  `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore`.

Comment: Thanks - I found the registry entry for Python 3.4 there. But why is Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" ?

Comment: That's the [new launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).